# How to get image faster from Dahua's IP Camera in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm developing software which access to Dahua's IP camera and get image from it.

Now, I use HTTP stream to get image like below.

```
string url = "http://IP adress:Port/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", <password>);
Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[3000 * 4000];
while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 10000)) != 0)
{
    total += read;
}
```

To use code above, I can get image from camera. But it takes more than 2 seconds.
I want to get image more faster.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess at a very high level either 1) the camera is slow 2) the network is slow or 3) this code is slow. How fast can you get images from the camera by other methods, e.g. the camera's web interface? If you look in your browser debug tools how much delay is there at the camera end before it response? Can you try accessing the camera over a wired connection to eliminate problems with the network?

Comment: To mjwills.   Thanks for your replying.  I prepare such a big buffer because the size of image is 3000x4000. I didn't know how many size of array I have to prepare.

Comment: To Rup.  Thank you for your replying. We can use software which dahua developed. We can access the camera almost in real-time. And, they also developed SDK.  I'm facing some problems. For examples, I can login to the camera but I don't know how to get image . They made a sample codes in Visual C# but it's difficult for me to understand what they implemented. You can find the SDK and I refer to the sample named RealPlayDemo (refer to: https://www.dahuasecurity.com/support/downloadCenter/download-search?keyword=Sdk&us)

Comment: To make sure it's not your code that's slow, test with a more basic tool to grab the data. The latest Windows 10 ships with `curl` that you can use on the command prompt. See [here](https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-auth) on how to use it with authentication. If your Windows doesn't have it, you can download curl from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/).  If even that is slow, then your problem is on the camera/network.